# Koach hasabal or Koach hasevel

Tags: tefilla, vowels-nekudot

In Tefila qodem hatfila from the Noam Elimelech one statement is:

> וכשל כוח הסבל מרוב הצרות. ‏

In modern hebrew the nikkud needs to be SEVEL (segol,  rafe,  segol).  But in all siddurim the nikkud is SABOL (patach,  daggesh chazak,  kamats).

The word כוח הסבל refers to the strength to endure. What is the reason for the actual nikkud in siddurim?

Comment: @paquda shkoyech!  Interesting,  Rashi and Ralbag translated this as the "mover"  Sabal in modern  hebrew

Comment: Yes, kouty, the same word as mover, someone who professionally carries loads.

Comment: @paquda perhaps you can include this in the answer, it is very interesting to note misunderstandings from modern hebrew Koach Hasevel is an usual expression in hebrew and Israeli people has tendency to read texts with this a priori. Sabal is aslo an usual word in modern hebrew, for mover. And it is very hard to see that the noam elimelech paraphrase pasuk. if no "the strength of the mover" is strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form סַבָּל / sabbāl, meaning 'bearer of burdens', is based on [Nehemiah 4:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b04.htm#4):

> וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוּדָה כָּשַׁל כֹּחַ הַסַּבָּל וְהֶעָפָר הַרְבֵּה וַאֲנַחְנוּ לֹא נוּכַל לִבְנוֹת בַּחוֹמָה
>
> And Judah said: 'The strength of the bearers of burdens is decayed, and there is much rubbish; so that we are not able to build the wall.'

In general, that binyan/form, with a geminated middle radical (i.e., dagesh on ayin ha-po'al), indicates a human being who does something habitually or professionally, like hayyāt / tailor, mallāh / sailor. In the first verse of Tehillim, the same form is used for people who sin repeatedly: hattā'im / וּבְדֶרֶךְ חַטָּאִים לֹא עָמָד. The form can also be used for God, as in the word sallāh, meaning repeatedly forgiving: "ki el tov ve-sallāh atah".

So, the prayer of Reb Elimelekh is referring to the ability of those who bear burdens to do so (or their failure to be able to do so).